# Unable to switch back to brush tool to sketch on canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

So I have my brush and eraser tool. The problem I had was at first I can sketch on canvas but after I switched to eraser, then if I select brush again, it stays at eraser tool. I tried using if else but couldn't make it work.

```
tool = new brushTool();
$('#brushTool').click(brushTool);
function brushTool() {
    var tool = this;
    this.mouseStart = false;

$('#eraserTool').click(eraserTool);
function eraserTool() {
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    context.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
}


    this.mousedown = function (e) {
        tool.mouseStart = true;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x, y);
        context.lineTo(x,y);
        context.lineCap = 'round';
        context.lineWidth = document.getElementById('brush_size').value;
        context.strokeStyle = document.getElementById('color').value;
        context.stroke();
    };


    this.mousemove = function (e) {
      if (tool.mouseStart) {
        context.lineTo(x, y);
        context.stroke();
      }
    };

    this.mouseup = function (e) {
      if (tool.mouseStart) {
        tool.mousemove(e);
        tool.mouseStart = false;
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos for your using javascript “classes” !

Here’s how to make your Tool class.

It looks like you want the Tool to function as either a brush or an eraser so your Tool class needs a “type” variable to know it’s current mode (brush/eraser)

```
    // create your Tool “class”
    function Tool(){

        // this is your tool’s current mode: none, brush, eraser
        var type="none";

    }
```

Here’s how to add functionality to your Tool class (often called methods—but they’re actually javascript functions).

You can declare class methods **outside** the “function Tool()” definition using prototype.  This way, every Tool object isn’t weighed down by it’s own copy of your methods.  If you create 10 Tools, they will all be able to use the common methods you define on the prototype.

```
    // this is where you define what you want the tool to do now (brush/eraser)
    Tool.prototype.activate=function(newType){ … };

    // start a new line (called by tool.mousedown)
    Tool.prototype.startLine=function(){ … };

    // draw a new line segment (called by tool.mousemove)
    Tool.prototype.drawLineTo=function(){ … }

    // called by jQuery when the user presses down the mousebutton
    Tool.prototype.mousedown=function(e){ … }

    // called by jQuery when the user moves the mouse
    Tool.prototype.mouseup=function(e){ … }
```

At this point, your Tool class is just a blueprint.  To create an actual tool, you use “new”.  This actual tool is called an object.

```
    var myTool=new Tool();
```

Then you can use any of the methods (functions) on myTool

```
    // call the “activate” method/function on your new myTool object.
    myTool.activate("brush");
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/sTAve/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    #brush_size,#color{ width:30px;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    // Note: every "this" refers to the tool

    // make a generic tool that can work as either a brush or eraser

    // first, set the properties that your tool has
    function Tool(){
        var type="none";
        var mouseStart=false;
        var x;
        var y;
        var lastX;
        var lastY;
    }

    // second, add the methods (functions) that your tool
    // these methods actually do the work

    // tool.activate()
    Tool.prototype.activate=function(newType){

        this.type=newType;
        this.mouseStart=false;

        // set your brush properties here
        if(this.type=="brush"){
          context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        }

        // set your eraser properties here
        if(this.type=="eraser"){
          context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
          context.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
        }

        console.log(this.type+": "+context.globalCompositeOperation);
    }

    //tool.startLine()
    Tool.prototype.startLine=function(){
        this.lastX=this.x;
        this.lastY=this.y;
        context.lineCap = 'round';
        context.lineWidth = document.getElementById("brush_size").value;
        if(this.type=="brush"){
            context.strokeStyle = document.getElementById('color').value;
        }
    console.log(context.strokeStyle);
    }

    // tool.drawLineTo()
    Tool.prototype.drawLineTo=function(){
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(this.lastX,this.lastY);
        context.lineTo(this.x,this.y);
        context.stroke();     
        this.lastX=this.x;
        this.lastY=this.y;
    //console.log(this.x+"/"+this.y+": "+this.mouseStart);
    }

    // tool.mousedown(e)
    Tool.prototype.mousedown=function(e){
        this.setXY(e);
        this.mouseStart = true;
        this.startLine(this.x,this.y);
    }

    // tool.mousemove(e)
    Tool.prototype.mousemove=function(e){
        if (this.mouseStart) {
          this.setXY(e);
          this.drawLineTo(this.x,this.y);
        }
    }

    // tool.mouseup(e)
    Tool.prototype.mouseup=function(e){
        if (this.mouseStart) {
          this.setXY(e);
          this.drawLine;
          this.mouseStart = false;
        }
    }

    // tool.setXY(e)
    Tool.prototype.setXY=function(e){
        this.x=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        this.y=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
    }


    // get references to the canvas and it's context
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // get the position of the canvas on the page
    // (needed to calculate mouse position later)
    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    // make a new tool
    var myTool=new Tool();
    myTool.activate("brush");

    // set some defaults
    document.getElementById("brush_size").value=15;
    document.getElementById('color').value="green";


    // listen for events

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){myTool.mousedown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){myTool.mousemove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){myTool.mouseup(e);});

    $('#eraserTool').click(function(e){ myTool.activate("eraser"); });
    $('#brushTool').click(function(e){ myTool.activate("brush"); });



}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="brushTool">Brush</button>
    <button id="eraserTool">Eraser</button>
    <input id="brush_size" type="text" width=10>
    <input id="color" type="text" width=10><br/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and Fiddle! Helped me a lot! 
I'm just wondering, is it possible to declare class method outside the function Tool() without using prototype?

Comment: Hmmm...adding to a class prototype is the way...any reason why you wouldn't want to do it this way?  You **can** add methods to a tool object you have newed up like this: var t=new Tool(); t.addedFn=function(){ alert("new"); }; t.addedFn(); [runs just fine!]. But if you want to create **variations** on your tool class--let's say a tool class whose brush is a gradient instead of a solid color, then you should check out javascript class "inheritance".

Comment: No reason. I'm just comparing the difference with and without prototype because I was a bit vague with the usage of prototype.
Yea. I had the idea of adding gradient to the brush but haven't figure out how. So, thanks for the head start.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer acceptance. I'm kinda new here. So, I'm just getting used to how things work lol. Anyway, sorry I can't put it as useful due to my reputation.

Comment: No problems here :)  Welcome to stackoverflow!